# jQuery Sortable not outputing order of sortable list on update

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am really at a loss to why this isn't working, this should really be a simple straight forword task.

I have the following code that I am using to create a sortable list. The list works and is sortable however it will not alert the order to the user.

```
<html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src='js/jquery.sortable.js'></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {
            $("#projectItems").sortable({
                update: function (event, ui) {

                    var order = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
                    alert(order);
                }
            });

        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="projectItems">
        <div id="item1">(1)</div>
        <div id="item2">(2)</div>
        <div id="item3">(3)</div>
        <div id="item4">(4)</div>
        <div id="item5">(5)</div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I am using the same code in this fiddle link and it seems to work fine? http://jsfiddle.net/FUXys/1/

There are no errors found in the error console either.

Why would this not be alerting the order when it works exactly the same in fiddle?

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

Here is the code from my jquery.sortable.js:

```
/** HTML5 Sortable jQuery Plugin
 * http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable
 * 
 * Copyright 2012, Ali Farhadi
 * Released under the MIT license.
 */
(function($) {
var dragging, placeholders = $();
$.fn.sortable = function(options) {
    var method = String(options);
    options = $.extend({
        connectWith: false
    }, options);
    return this.each(function() {
        if (/^enable|disable|destroy$/.test(method)) {
           var items =  $(this).children($(this).data('items')).attr('draggable', method == 'enable');
        if (method == 'destroy') {
            items.add(this).removeData('connectWith items')
                .off('dragstart.h5s dragend.h5s selectstart.h5s dragover.h5s dragenter.h5s drop.h5s');
        }
        return;
    }
    var isHandle, index, items = $(this).children(options.items);
    var placeholder = $('<' + (/^ul|ol$/i.test(this.tagName) ? 'li' : 'div') + ' class="sortable-placeholder">');
    items.find(options.handle).mousedown(function() {
        isHandle = true;
    }).mouseup(function() {
        isHandle = false;
    });
    $(this).data('items', options.items)
    placeholders = placeholders.add(placeholder);
    if (options.connectWith) {
        $(options.connectWith).add(this).data('connectWith', options.connectWith);
    }
    items.attr('draggable', 'true').on('dragstart.h5s', function(e) {
        if (options.handle && !isHandle) {
            return false;
        }
        isHandle = false;
        var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
        dt.effectAllowed = 'move';
        dt.setData('Text', 'dummy');
        index = (dragging = $(this)).addClass('sortable-dragging').index();
    }).on('dragend.h5s', function() {
        dragging.removeClass('sortable-dragging').show();
        placeholders.detach();
        if (index != dragging.index()) {
            items.parent().trigger('sortupdate', {item: dragging});
        }
        dragging = null;
    }).not('a[href], img').on('selectstart.h5s', function() {
        this.dragDrop && this.dragDrop();
        return false;
    }).end().add([this, placeholder]).on('dragover.h5s dragenter.h5s drop.h5s', function(e) {
        if (!items.is(dragging) && options.connectWith !== $(dragging).parent().data('connectWith')) {
            return true;
        }
        if (e.type == 'drop') {
            e.stopPropagation();
            placeholders.filter(':visible').after(dragging);
            return false;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
        if (items.is(this)) {
            if (options.forcePlaceholderSize) {
                placeholder.height(dragging.outerHeight());
            }
            dragging.hide();
            $(this)[placeholder.index() < $(this).index() ? 'after' : 'before'](placeholder);
            placeholders.not(placeholder).detach();
        } else if (!placeholders.is(this) && !$(this).children(options.items).length) {
            placeholders.detach();
            $(this).append(placeholder);
        }
        return false;
    });
});
};
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you per chance using this plugin? https://github.com/johnny/jquery-sortable

This plugin does not support the '**update**' parameter. Instead, you'd have to do something like

```
$("#projectItems").sortable({
    onDrop: function  (item, container, _super) {
      _super(item)
      console.log(container.items) // already an array
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think this is the plugin I'm using.
I have tried your suggestion above however and it is not outputting anything to the console. Are there over versions of the Sortable Plugin that you could recommend?

Comment: I installed jquery-sortable via bower and it uses this version you linked. Switching to onDrop works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`stop( event, ui )`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop) instead of [`update( event, ui )`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update).

```
$("#projectItems").sortable({
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        var order = $("#projectItems").sortable('toArray').toString();
        console.log(order);
    }
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/FUXys/2/

---

Side Note: Make sure to use [`console.log()`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) instead of `alert()`.  You will thank me.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I've tried your suggestion above without success. I am checking the web console for the response, is that where it should respond to?
Any further suggest on how I could fix this issue would be appreciated as it's starting to drive me crazy!

Comment: Yes, check the console and it should appear there. If not, let me know and we will figure out what is going on.

Comment: I have added the content of jquery.sortable.js to the post for you to see.
I have tried your method above, however nothing is being output to the console.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, it turns out it was to do with the jquery.sortable.js file. I download a different version from http://jqueryui.com/download/ and it is working fine now.

I can output the order now as an alert or a console.log.

Thanks to Dom and P.Kelly for pointing me in the correct direction.